# How to set Focus Visual Style to a Line in WPF

Tags: wpf, line

I am having Line control in my UI. If Select that line in the case It should be focused and Focus Visual Style would get applied. I have tried the below code, but it is not working.Whether the way that i am trying is right or wrong?

code:

```
 <Line x:Name="line" X1="50" Y1="20" X2="90" Y2="50" Stroke="Red" Fill="Bisque" StrokeThickness="5" FocusVisualStyle="{DynamicResource MyFocusVisualStyle}" Focusable="True"  />
```

Kindly Guide me on this.

Thanks.

Comment: `FocusVisualStyle` is gained when it is invoked via `Keyboard`. If you want to set `Focus` on a line via `Mouse` click, you can simply use `MouseUp` & `MouseDown` event for the line and set its `Stroke` color to something you would like to be shown as _selected_

Comment: Thanks for the information. Is there any other ways to add a border around line on selection? I mean any other properties like FocusVisualStyle?

Comment: Sorry I haven't ever implemented a border around a line, I mostly do what I mentioned in the comment. Plus to show selection I would use `StrokeDashArray` property also, which convincingly works fine for me

Comment: Would you like a solution on what I do to make that happen, implement my solution once, and if you like it, you can go with it! Else wait for someone from the community who knows more that me to answer a better solution :)

Comment: How do you "select" the line?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what is there in `MyFocusVisualStyle` and where it is located, but the following example could give you a heads up. Also make sure you navigate to the line with keyboard tab key hitting so that it can catch focus.
The following code will draw a polygon around the line based on line's coordinates.

```
 <Line  x:Name="line" X1="50" Y1="20" X2="200" Y2="50" Stroke="Red" Fill="Bisque" StrokeThickness="5"  Focusable="True" >
    <Line.FocusVisualStyle>
        <Style>
            <Setter Property="Control.Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate>
                        <Polygon Points="49 22 200 52 200 49 49 18" Stroke="Green" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2" />
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </Line.FocusVisualStyle>
 </Line>
```